# Collection select categories and sub categories | not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having troubles creating subcategories in my new form: 
 I followed [this example](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections) from simple form documentation but with no success...

**product**

```
belongs_to :category
```

**category**

```
has_many :products
belongs_to :main_category
```

**main_category**

```
has_many :categories
has_many :products, through: :categories
```

This is my product form :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product, url: admin_products_path)do |f| %>    
  <%= f.input :category_id, as: :grouped_select, collection: MainCategory.all, group_method: :categories, input_html: { class: "custom-select"}, label: false, prompt: "Choisir une catégorie" %>
  #[...]
<%= f.submit  %>
```

[image]

I tried to retrieve the attribute `:gender` like this

```
<%= f.input :category_id, as: :grouped_select, collection: MainCategory.all.map {|mc| mc.gender}, group_method: :categories, input_html: { class: "custom-select"}, label: false, prompt: "Choisir une catégorie" %>
```

but it returns the error `undefined method categories' for "Men":String`

How can I do to have the main category's title to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

adding `group_label_method: :gender` should made the job

```
<%= f.input :category_id, as: :grouped_select, collection: MainCategory.all,
    group_method: :categories, 
    group_label_method: :gender, 
    input_html: { class: "custom-select"}, 
    label: false, 
    prompt: "Choisir une catégorie" %>
```